# Subtree Dissappears from Sourcetree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, subtree

I am creating successfully a subtree to a remote repo and pull/push successfully using Sourcetree. The substree repo appears below "Stashes" tab on the left of Sourcetree as "Subtree" tab.

However, when I close and reopen the Sourcetree, the "Subtree" tab and the subtree that I have defined earlier, disappears.

It does not disappear, if I close the project tab and reopen the project without closing the Sourcetree.

I have seen these two post with the same/similar problem:

[First Post](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1620?error=login_required&error_description=Login%20required&state=29b43196-eba6-48a1-b475-cc5b07cafa94)

[Second Post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/subtree-pull-hangs-or-pulls-into-the-wrong-folder/qaq-p/368478)

Both links belong to the same person.

I have tried the suggested solution there (clearing cache) but it did not solve my problem.

The person, who was in charge of developing this part of the Sourcetree, has not posted since 2017. Maybe he left Atlassian, and this issue is still there.

I have already asked this question in the Sourcetree forum, but no replies since April.

I have opened a bug report at [this link](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13288?filter=-8)

I have tried version 3.3.9 and the problem is still there.

It seems to be a simple "save" issue. I also remember that Sourcetree did not have this issue in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is consequence of another major issue with Sourcetree versions came after 3.2.6. After this version, a major bug is introduced, probably something related to authentication, and it results a constant red exclamation mark on the remote button. This mark can be fixed in version 3.2.6, but not in the later versions. So, I am staying with version 3.2.6 for now.